Getting Bean isssue while migrating Spring boot 2.7.2 to 3.2.1
`Hi all,
I trying to migrate my project from spring 2.7.2 to spring boot 3.2.1 but getting error expected single matching bean but found 2 mock service,service and if I added @Primary on mockService getting multiple @Primary not allowed,I am not sure why it’s working in 2.7.2 version @Primary in static class , any idea?
=========ResolverSpec.groovy========
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig)
class ResolverSpec extends HttpControllerSpec {
    @Autowired
  Resolver resolver

    @Autowired
    Service testService

    User adminUser
    User user

    def setup() {
        adminUser = newAdminUser()
        user = newUser(adminUser.getAccount())
    }

def "should execute proper query for enroll on behalf and return #expected for #input"(Resource resource, PeqlResponse input, int type, boolean expected) {
    given:
    def onBehalfOf = seqId()
    def permissionsHolderId = seqId()

    and:
    when(testService.query(eq(adminUser.accountId), any(BatchQuery) as BatchQuery)).thenReturn(input)

    and:
    verifyQury(adminUser.accountId, enrollOnBehalf(adminUser.id, onBehalfOf, permissionsHolderId, type)
}

static class TestConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    Service testService() {
        mock(Service.class)
    }
}

==============TestConfig.groovy=========
@Configuration
class TestConfig {

    ———@Primary——
    @Bean
    MockService mockService() {
        new MockService()
    }
}

====================ActivitiesConfiguration.java===========
@Configuration
public class ActivitiesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Service service(
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry,
            HttpClient httpClient) {
        return new RemoteService(serviceRegistry, httpClient);
    }
}

I removed @Primary from static class and added at mockService`
